# Heroku gets wrong filepath for index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I tried to start my discord bot via heroku and it didn't start, when i checked the logs it gave me this response

```
Starting...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'Discord.js'
Require stack:
- /app/index.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:3:29)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
}
```

To me it seems like it tries to start the `index.js` file through the filepath `/app/index.js` but the file is not located in `/app/index.js` but instead just `/index.js` and I never even entered anything about the `/app` filepath anywhere so I dont know why it does this

Edit: I realised that the logs didnt show anything useful ton search because I entered the logs too late and if I entered them earlier I would see more info about the error. Heres what it said earlier

```
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
}
Process exited with status 1
State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably located in the `package.json` file because there is a field called main there which defines where your main file is located.

```
{
    "name": "lhubot",
    "version": "2.2.6",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    ...
}
```

Comment: "I will be using answers to reply because I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet"—please don't do this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input @Chris . I knew "I will be using answers to reply because I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet" was bad but did not know it was that bad. On the other hand did not know posting text screenshots was forbidden, won't do that again. I fixed both answers now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer myself, i wrote the wrong name for discord.js in `require('discord.js')`. I wrote "Discord.js" instead of "discord.js". Not sure why heroku found it as a problem but it was fine when i ran it on my own computer but that was the solution for me.