# Program that takes name from api and finds first google image and saves it under that name

Tags: image, automation, email-validation

I am working on a college website, I am adding email validation using api that has thousands of colleges names. I want to make the interface a bit more personalized using images of the college as the page cover. But as mentioned it has thousands of names. when searching the name of the college on google the first result usually yields high res and nice looking image, would there be anyway to implement this to have it be the cover for all the respective colleges? I am new to programming and this is one of my first more complicated projects. Be nice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to use [this API](https://serpapi.com/images-results) to get Google images but you would also need another library (depends on the language/framework you are using) to extract the image from the API result (original field to be exact).

```
 "images_results": [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "thumbnail": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMzLN9iUjPiaNdA8w7NtzSTuJI0UPbDFOQKh3IXF6buUYmkaNr",
      "original": "https://as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/o/g/og/default/og-default?wid=1200&hei=630&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_usm=0.5,0.5&.v=1525370171638",
      "source": "apple.com",
      "title": "Apple Accessories for Apple Watch, iPhone, iPad, iPod, and Mac - Apple",
      "link": "https://www.apple.com/shop/accessories/all-accessories"
    },
```

Comment: "I will be using answers to reply because I don't have enough reputation to add comments yet"—[again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70914652/354577), please don't do this. You seem to know the rules, so don't break them. It just makes more work for other users to clean up. And again, please post text as _text_.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I as looking for! I am using react native for ios and android app

Comment: Alright, then this library should do: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch . Even tho there are multiple alternatives found here https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode . @MohammadJihad